# std::map with pointers: wrong value assess

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, dictionary, reference

I am trying to save into the **STL map a pointer** to the **Block** object:

```
void IO::parseInput(void)
{
    map<string, Block*> blocksMap;

    //=== Create new block and write it to the vector in database ===
    Block tmpBlock (bIndex, bName, bWidth, bHeight);
    Block* tmpPointer = db.addBlock(tmpBlock); //addBlock returns pointer to the added Block

    tmpPointer->printParams(); // -- here is correct output

    blocksMap.insert ( pair<string, Block*>(bName, tmpPointer) );

    // === Test hash ===
    blocksMap.find("anyLegalStringKey")->second->printParams(); // -- wrong output
}
```

addBlock function in DB class:

```
Block* DB::addBlock (Block& newBlock)
{
    blocks.push_back(newBlock);
    Block* ptrToLast = &blocks.back();
    return ptrToLast;
}
```

Vector of Block's in DB class:

```
class DB:
{
    private:
    //=== Database ===
    vector <Block> blocks;
};
```

**Problem:** Before writing into the map I access to the object (which pointer I want to save) using pointer **tmpPointer** and print all its parameters. This one works correct. Then I save this pointer in map with specific key. When i try then to access the same pointer using find in map with specific key, I get a wrong output (I also print all parameters).

When I try to access to pointers in map for any existed key it could lead to four different reactions:

1. Everything is OK and I get normal output (in my case I print all parameters)
2. I get wrong parameters (e.g. instead of index 7 I got 21814704)
3. Unreadable output
4. Segmentation fault

Interesting is that for the same Block object I have always same reaction (e.g. block with name "g22i" has always unreadable output).

Vector "blocks" in db contains correct info before and after I save pointers in map.

Thanks!

Comment: When you `push_back` into a vector, the vector can grow, which requires a re-allocation. This invalidates references and iterators to its elements.

Comment: You should *always* check the result of `.find` to make sure `.find() != blocksMap.end()`. Dereferencing `.end()` is undefined behavior, and it it did not find anything, you dereference as soon as you call `->second`

Comment: Store the blocks in your vector as pointers, preferably `unique_ptr<Block>`. Pointers to these blocks won't change when pushing back more. Alternatively, store indices in your map, to look up in the vector.

Comment: general advice: use smart pointers (std::shared_ptr)  instead of naked ptrs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to use long-lived pointers to `std::vector`'s elements. That's a recipe for disaster. All such pointers will be invalidated the very moment your vector decides to reallocate itself.

If you want to use pointers to vector elements, you have to make sure the vector never reallocates. I.e. you have to reserve enough capacity in advance to store all future elements. Most of the time it is suboptimal, defeats the purpose of using `std::vector` or plain impossible.

You can also use a container that never invalidates pointers to its elements, like `std::list`. But `std::list` does not support random access. You can use `std::deque`, which supports random access (albeit less efficiently than `std::vector`) and preserves the validity of element pointers as long as you don't insert anything into the middle of the sequence.

Finally, you can keep using `std::vector`, but make sure to store [smart] pointers to `Block` objects in it instead of `Block` objects themselves. The idea is to ensure that vector reallocation does not cause reallocation of the actual `Block` objects.

**P.S.** Another remark: when you declare a `map<string, Block*> blocksMap`, elements of such map have type `pair<const string, Block*>` (note the extra `const`). I.e. `map<string, Block*>::value_type` is actually `pair<const string, Block*>`.

Later you are trying to call `blocksMap.insert` with `pair<string, Block*>` argument, while `blocksMap.insert` actually expects `pair<const string, Block*>`. This compiles, but it involves an implicit conversion from your `pair<string, Block*>` to `pair<const string, Block*>` performed by `std::pair`'s conversion constructor. This is not optimal performance-wise. Which is why a better idea might be to use `map<string, Block*>::value_type` instead of trying to spell the element type manually

```
blocksMap.insert ( map<string, Block*>::value_type(bName, tmpPointer) );
```